# How to `dot` weights to batch data in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have batch data and want to `dot()` to the data. W is trainable parameters.
How to dot between batch data and weights?

```
hid_dim = 32
data = torch.randn(10, 2, 3, hid_dim)
data = data.view(10, 2*3, hid_dim)
W = torch.randn(hid_dim) # assume trainable parameters via nn.Parameter
result = torch.bmm(data, W).squeeze() # error, want (N, 6)
result = result.view(10, 2, 3)
```

### Update

How about this one?

```
hid_dim = 32
data = torch.randn(10, 2, 3, hid_dim)
data = tdata.view(10, 2*3, hid_dim)
W = torch.randn(hid_dim, 1) # assume trainable parameters via nn.Parameter
W = W.unsqueeze(0).expand(10, hid_dim, 1)
result = torch.bmm(data, W).squeeze() # error, want (N, 6)
result = result.view(10, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand `W` tensor to match the shape of `data` tensor. The following should work.

```
hid_dim = 32
data = torch.randn(10, 2, 3, hid_dim)
data = data.view(10, 2*3, hid_dim)
W = torch.randn(hid_dim)
W = W.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).expand(*data.size())
result = torch.sum(data * W, 2)
result = result.view(10, 2, 3)
```

---

**Edit**: Your updated code is correct. Since you are converting `W` to a `Bxhid_dimx1` and your data is of shape `Bxdxhid_dim`, so doing batch matrix multiplication will result in `Bxdx1` which is essentially the dot product between `W` parameter and all the row vectors in `data` (`dxhid_dim`).

Comment: I updated my post. But your code looks better than me. Is my code also correct?